# Two-state Markov chain-showing relation

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The following exercise comes from the book *Probability, Markov Chains, Queues, and Simulation*.

> Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ be a two-state Markov chain, whose transition probability matrix is given by
>   $$
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     1-p & p \\
>     q & 1-q \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   with $0 < p, q < 1$. Use the fact that ${P}^{n+1}={P}^n*P$ to show that $p_{11}^{(n+1)}=(1-p-q)p_{11}^{(n)}+q$.

---

I struggle with a few things. First of all, what is the exact difference between the powers ${(n+1)}$ and ${n+1}$ ? My assumption is that the former refers to transitioning to the other state, the latter is just putting to the power of $n + 1$, but the book does not mention it explicitly. If this is right, then is $p_{11}^{(n+1)}$ equal to $(1-p)^{(n+1)}$ ? What should be the next step? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What book are your reading? $p^{(n+1)}_{11}$ seems like the probability to come back to state $1$ in $n+1$ steps to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment, in this case $p^{(n+1)}_{11}$  means the probability that the MC comes back to state $1$, starting from $1$, at its $n+1$th step.

Please consider

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    p^{n+1}_{11} & p^{n+1}_{12} \\
    p^{n+1}_{21} & p^{n+1}_{22} \\
    \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}     p^{n}_{11} & p^{n}_{12} \\
    p^{n}_{21} & p^{n}_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}     1-p & p \\
    q & 1-q \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you solve RHS of the equation, then

$p^{n+1}_{11} = p^{n}_{11}(1-p) + p^{n}_{12}q = p^{n}_{11}(1-p) + (1-p^{n}_{11})q =(1-p-q)p_{11}^{(n)}+q$.

Comment: thanks, but why does the second row of the left matrix start with P_21 and the second row of the middle with P_12 ?

Comment: Oops sorry that was a mistake. I fixed it.